# Use rsync to move DB2 Archlog files including path

Tags: linux, unix, rsync

I try to move DB2 Archive Log files to a /backup filesystem before I do additional actions on them. **Important here is that we preserv the full path.**

`tar -czvf $OUTFILE db2/???/log_archive/db2???/???/NODE*/LOGSTREAM*/C*/* --remove-files`

At the moment I use tar from the root,but it has some downsides; if prefer that the files are simply moved.
So therefore I am playing with rsync, like for instance:

`rsync -nrv --include='/db2/???/log_archive/*' --include '*.LOG' --exclude '*' --prune-empty-dirs / /backup`

But what ever I try.... or I have just (nearly) all files and folders from root, or nothing at all.
Does anyone have a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

When I noticed that rsync can work with "files-from", I managed it in a totally other way..... 
So to move the DB2 Log files to a different /backup filesystem and preserving full path, I can use `find` and then `rsync`

```
find /db2/???/log_archive/* -name *.LOG -type f -mmin +1 | rsync -rv --files-from=- --remove-source-files / /backup/
sending incremental file list
db2/
db2/BWP/
db2/BWP/log_archive/
db2/BWP/log_archive/db2bwp/
db2/BWP/log_archive/db2bwp/BWP/
db2/BWP/log_archive/db2bwp/BWP/NODE0000/
db2/BWP/log_archive/db2bwp/BWP/NODE0000/LOGSTREAM0000/
db2/BWP/log_archive/db2bwp/BWP/NODE0000/LOGSTREAM0000/C0000000/
db2/BWP/log_archive/db2bwp/BWP/NODE0000/LOGSTREAM0000/C0000000/S0006869.LOG
db2/BWP/log_archive/db2bwp/BWP/NODE0000/LOGSTREAM0000/C0000000/S0006870.LOG
db2/BWP/log_archive/db2bwp/BWP/NODE0000/LOGSTREAM0000/C0000000/S0006871.LOG
db2/BWP/log_archive/db2bwp/BWP/NODE0000/LOGSTREAM0000/C0000000/S0006872.LOG
db2/BWP/log_archive/db2bwp/BWP/NODE0000/LOGSTREAM0000/C0000000/S0006873.LOG
etc etc etc
```

Here I use 'find' to select the files (older then 1 minute to ensure DB2 is finished with archiving this file) and then transport this list of files to 'rsync' who moves them to the new location.